# My favorite tags are empty

Tags: support, bug, tags

I am searching for unanswered questions on my favorite tags (mysql, lubuntu, virtualbox, and etc.) 
But all of them are empty (zero unanswered) is this right? Or I'm having some kind of trouble?

Could it  be a bug?

Comment: This might be a bug. For example, when I go to `mysql` and click *Unanswered*, it brings me to the [unanswered tab](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mysql?sort=unanswered&pagesize=50) where I see 39 questions listed. Hopefully a mod will answer more definitively soon.

Comment: I checked last time and it works again... don't know if that was a bug after all... I upgraded my firefox to `14.0.1`. thanks anyway